# How do I convert data from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 without any Broken characters

Tags: c#, html, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have tried to export html data to database with UTF-8 encoding.But I am seeing some "Broken characters" in the database.For example:

while exporting the html data

·         A contribution  .....

·         Choice between two .............

into the database with UTF-8.The (.)midpoint in the data is converted in to (Â.).I need to convert the data explicitly to ISO-8859-1 by removing the broken character in c#. Is there any way to do that ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your title is quite absurd. Technically there is no way to convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 without loss. This is because UTF-8 can theoretically encode a *million* characters whereas ISO-8859-1 can only encode 256.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to specify methods to be invoked in order to handle bad characters when encoding and decoding. You can substitute other characters, or throw an exception, or provide logging etc.

See [this overload of GetEncoding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89856k4b.aspx) for details.

Comment: I cant able to substitute other characters every time.Since, I am not sure about the bad characters to be present in the data